# Excel-VBA-The first part of the IF-Else statement with the variable does not answer

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have a VBA code for a button to increase value of cells in turn in excel.
code is this:

```
Dim current_row As Long '<-- global variable Current Row
Sub Button6_Click()
    current_row = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(current_row, 7) = 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(18, 1) = 555555
        current_row = 11  '<-- return to first record row at the end of table-end of table has 0 value
    Else
        current_row = current_row + 1 '<--increases of 1 each click
    End If
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(current_row, 7) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(current_row, 7) + 1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = current_row
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(17, 1) = current_row
End Sub
```

in first part of IF clause when I use current_row, condition is never true **(However,value of current_row changes correctly, and I've added a command for the temporary display current_value that displays correct in cell row 18 and column 1 )** but when I write a number instead of current_row variable and target cell has zero value, first of IF is true and continue correctly.
this code apply for a table like this:

```
+=============+========================+
| **Name**    |**Number of tasks done**|
+=============+========================+
| Joe         |                      3 |
+-------------+------------------------+
| John        |                      2 |
+-------------+------------------------+
| Emma        |                      1 |
+-------------+------------------------+
| Sophia      |                      1 |
+-------------+------------------------+
|End of Table |                      0 |
+-------------+------------------------+
```

**Meanwhile, I cleared all cells values after the end of table that all of them was 1, and write in the end of table zero, or left the cell end of the table blank, without manipulating, took the starting value from the first number The rows of the table and started to increase from the start of the table, but again continued after the end of the table to insert 1 value and continued the same problem**

Can you say whats the problem, please?

Comment: Is the contents of the cell you are checking a number - does it have any hidden characters?

Comment: Make sure you use `Option Explicit` to avoid typos in variable names. And which value does `Debug.Print Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(current_row, 7)` return when you expect it to be `0`?

Comment: @SolarMike......No

Comment: @harixprog4 if it is not a number then what are you testing for?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Display four last numbers

Comment: @harixprog4 ① Be more precise please! I don't have a crystal ball where I can see your sheet. And I have no clue what "four last numbers" is. ② If it shows numbers then your cell is not `0`, so either you are not in the row you think or not in the column you think.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ displays last four cells values that is number 1 or more.each number in a row.like the top table: shows 3 , 2 , 1 ,1.I'm sure it's in the same column and row because it exactly changes the values of the cells of the same column that needs to be changed, but when it reaches the end of the table that is 0 , The current_row value does not change to the beginning of the table , makes it 1, and the rest of the cells that are empty are also with Every time it clicks

Comment: What if you change it to `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(current_row, 7).Value = 0`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I use option Explicit but was not helpful

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I changed to Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(current_row, 7).Value = 0 but didnt work

Comment: So you said it shows `3 , 2 , 1 ,1` what does it show on the end of table then, when you expect it to be `0`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ show 0 and After several times running of the code, displays the blank page and does not show any value or string.

Comment: Meanwhile, I cleared all cells values after the end of table that all of them was 1, and write in the end of table zero, or left the cell in end of the table after that, blank, without manipulating, took the starting value from the first number The rows of the table and started to increase from the start of the table, but again continued after the end of the table to insert 1 value and continued the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

Before IF statement, value of the variable was received from the specified cell, and it was checked in the condition that if the cell value was equal to zero, then one unit adds to the variable, and then the cell was initialized based on the next to current_row. means the amount of the current cell was checked that it was 0 or not, but the next cell was initialized so that the value of the end of table, which was zero, always changed and never zero before or after the review.

The correct code is this:

```
Dim current_row As Long '<-- global variable Current Row
Sub Button6_Click()
    current_row = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(current_row, 7) = "end" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(18, 1) = 5453
        current_row = 11
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(current_row, 7) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(current_row, 7) + 1
        current_row = current_row + 1
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(current_row, 7) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(current_row, 7) + 1
        current_row = current_row + 1 '<--increases of 1 each click
    End If
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = current_row
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(17, 1) = current_row
End Sub
```

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the clause of the if statement from:

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(current_row, 7)=0
```

to:

```
If Int(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(current_row, 7))=0
```

This simply will treat any value you have in your column as integer.

Comment: So Why when I write a number instead of current_row variable and target cell has zero value, first of IF is true and continue correctly. For example: **If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(18, 7)=0** 18 instead of current_value

Comment: @harixprog4 there is no variable named `current_value`. Make sure you use `Option Explicit`!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, Sorry I had a typo mistake. 18 instead of current_row

Comment: Does it work if you type 18 into cell A1 of Sheet2? `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)`

Comment: @harix, have you put Option Explicit in the top of the code as PEH suggested?

Comment: Yes but wasnt helpful